# Error Ubuntu 11.10 despues de instalar [Error after installing Ubuntu 11.10]

Tags: 11.10, wubi, smart

Instale Ubuntu 11.10, termino de instalar y no tiene nada, ni aplicaciones, ni esa barrita lateral de Unity, no tiene nada, ni si quiera la barra donde aparece la hora; ¿por qué? y me aparece un cuadro diciendo que hay un error en el disco y que el fallo es inminente, ¿qué es? SMART no entiendo, ayuda.

Y en otro disco duro con Windows XP SP3 se bloquea cuando lo instalo desde el Live CD, y desde wubi aparece esto, ¿qué hacer?:

[image]

---

**English translation (via Google Translate, edited)**

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10, after finishing the installing there is nothing, no applications, no the sidebar called unity, there is nothing, not even the bar where time appears, why?. I get a box saying there is an error on the disk and that failure is imminent. What is SMART, I do not understand, help

In my other hard drive, with Windows XP SP3, it crashes when I try install from the Live CD using wubi, this appears, what to do?

[image]

Comment: English please?

Comment: Y que dice el log? `c:\docume~\da\config~1\temp\wubi-11.10-rev241.log` agregalo a la pregunta... and what is in the log? `c:\docume~\da\config~1\temp\wubi-11.10-rev241.log` add it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, este sitio esta pensado para responder las preguntas una a una. Si tienes varias preguntas es mejor que las hagas por separado.

SMART es un sistema para predecir problemas con el disco duro. Lo más probable es que el disco duro en el que estas intentando instalar Ubuntu este dañado.

Para intentar solucionar el problema de WUBI lo mejor es que abras otra pregunta, e incluyas el archivo de registro que menciona el error.

---

First, this place work better if you ask one question at a time. If you have more questions it will be better if you ask them one by one.

SMART is hard disk problems prediction and monitoring system. The most likely problem is that this hard disk (where you are trying to install Ubuntu) is broken.

To be able to solve the WUBI problem, ask another question and include in it the contents of the log file indicated in the error message.